# Want to know the PCIe MMIO request payload unit size

Tags: memory, io, pci-e, memory-mapping, memory-mapped-io

I am searching for the unit size of the MMIO request when sending to the PCIe device BAR region from CPU.

I used this code. In the below code, you can see that the MMIO accessing code between the "////////////////" line.
I just used 32 bit value(pointer) to use for READ/WRITE request to PCIe device MMIO, I'm not sure what this request will be seperated?? or gathered(if the R/W request is followed more)?? and if the request will be separated or gathered, what size will be?? what the payload unit size will be??

```
#define MMIO_PHY_ADDR 0x20bf80000000
#define MMIO_SIZE 4096 // 4KB, that i want to map on the memory (Total BAR is 1GB but i used only 4KB for test)
#define MMIO_ACCESS_SIZE (MMIO_SIZE / sizeof(uint32_t)) // Number of 32-bit units

int main() {
    int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open /dev/mem");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    void* mmio_base = mmap(nullptr, MMIO_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, MMIO_PHY_ADDR);
    if (mmio_base == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Failed to mmap");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    printf("Memory mapped at virtual address %p.\n", mmio_base);

    uint32_t value = *((uint32_t*)mmio_base);
    std::cout << "Read value: 0x" << std::hex << value << std::endl;

    *((uint32_t*)mmio_base) = 0x12345678;
    std::cout << "Wrote 0x12345678 to the mapped memory" << std::endl;

    value = *((uint32_t*)mmio_base);
    std::cout << "Read value: 0x" << std::hex << value << std::endl;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Saying for just in case, my environment is Linux Ubuntu 5.4.0-172-generic and I am using Xilinx FPGA with Xilinx PCIe IP configured by myself as the PCIe device.
Below is the lspci result of the PCIe device.

```
27:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Device ****:**** (rev ****)
    Subsystem: **** Device ****
    Physical Slot: 2
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at 20bfc0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 2: Memory at 20bf80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=1G]
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <256ns, L1 <2us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 75.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr+ UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM not supported
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s (ok), Width x8 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
             10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS-, TPHComp-, ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn+
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+, EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+, EqualizationPhase3+, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [e0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [f8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=**** Rev=**** Len=**** <?>
    Capabilities: [120 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
        ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
    Capabilities: [200 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt+ UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC+ UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP+ FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 0f, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [300 v1] Secondary PCI Express
        LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn-, PerformEqu-
        LaneErrStat: LaneErr at lane: 0 5 6 7
```

I just used 32 bit value(pointer) to use for READ/WRITE request to PCIe device MMIO, I'm not sure what this request will be seperated?? or gathered(if the R/W request is followed more)?? and if the request will be separated or gathered, what size will be?? what the payload unit size will be??

Comment: On x86 CPUs, uncacheable accesses cannot be combined. They can be split if needed, but aligned accesses of 64 bits or less won't be split. Each UC access by the CPU is completed before the next one starts. I don't know about other types of CPUs, but I expect they are similar.

Comment: Thx for comment @prl then you means that the minimum unit of access will be 64bit ??

Comment: No, the size of the PCIe transaction is the size of the memory operand in the CPU instruction, if it  is 64 bits or less and properly aligned.

Comment: @prl Ah! Now I get it for read request unit size.
Also curious about the write request. If it is said to be uncacheable region, then is the write buffer for write request also not working?